# How to connect quarkus to mongodb using ssl

Tags: java, mongodb, quarkus

I need to connect my quarkus application to on-premise mongodb using ssl. I have certificate, pem and key files from mongodb. I am able to login to mongodb using compass with these details. What configuration changes should I do so that my quarkus-mongodb connection gets established.

Answer (score 0):

If you deploy your application inside a standard JVM, you need to integrate the certificate inside your JVM truststore using keytool.
This is the standard way to setup a non-trusted certificate inside a JVM.

If you deploy as a native executable (using GraalVM native-image), it's a little more complex as you need to build the native-executable with a JVM truststore that containes your certificate, see [Native and SSL](https://quarkus.io/guides/native-and-ssl).
You can also skip the hostname verification for a native executable, see [Building a native executable](https://quarkus.io/guides/mongodb#building-a-native-executable).

Comment: So please describe in your question the step you takes, the configuration you are using and the error you have so we can help you understand what's going on.

Comment: My requirement is to connect to ssl enabled mongo database. Above example enables https urls. I used https://www.codota.com/code/java/classes/javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory example to provide the certificate details to my mongoclient. My local quarkus code is able to connect to mongodb and junits are also working. But when I deploy the application in docker, junit test cases fails to connect to mongo and my build is unsuccessful.. If I disable junit, deployment is successful and connection is also established. Same code when called from junit, it fails.